# Reddit comments labeled data-set for sentiment analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, annotations, dataset, sentiment-analysis, reddit

Sorry for the vague question.

I was searching for a Reddit comments data-set which is labeled into three classes: positive, negative and neutral to train a ML model. I can get labeled data for tweets, movie reviews but what about Reddit. Is there any credible source for it?

PS: I don't want to annotate the data myself.

Comment: Questions about off-site resources are off-topic on StackOverflow, but you might be able to ask at [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/), a StackExchange site for open data sets.

Comment: Okay I ll take it there. Thanks.